# Angular Karma-Jasmine Unit Testing with EJS index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ejs

I am trying to implement front-end unit-tests on an Angular project which uses a server-side templating engine to render an `index.ejs` or `index.dust`. This file also includes a global variable `var cdn = "http://s3.amazon.com";` which is used throughout the angular app.

When I run`start karma karma.config.js`, I receive `ReferenceError: cdn is not defined: app.js L20`.

The `cdn` var is available when I run my app with Node, but when I try to run unit-tests on my Angular Ctrls, I receive the error above.

I tried to use the `karma-ejs-preprocessor` module (here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-ejs-preprocessor) to instantiate`cdn` in my tests, but I get a new error: `No provider for "framework: jasmine"`.

index.ejs

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>

    <script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>

    <script src="./app.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Angular Unit Testing</h1>

    <script>
      var cdn = "./";
    </script>

    <main>
      <div ui-view></div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

karma.conf.js

```
    // Karma configuration
// Generated on Sat Mar 12 2016 02:53:19 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'client/src/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'client/src/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      'client/src/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'client/src/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'client/src/app.js',
      'tests/test.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],

    plugins: [
      'karma-qunit',
      'karma-ejs-preprocessor',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-chrome-launcher'
    ],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      'server/_views/index.ejs': ['ejs']
    },

    ejsOptions: {
      parentPath: './server/_views/index.ejs'
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

test.js

```
describe('State1Ctrl', function () {
  var $rootScope,
      $scope,
      controller;

  beforeEach(function () {
    module('app', 'ui.router');

    inject(function ($injector) {
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      controller = $injector.get('$controller')('State1Ctrl', { $scope: $scope } );
    });
  });

  describe('Init', function () {
    it('should be init', function () {
      expect($scope.test).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

app.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router'
  ])

  .controller('State1Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    console.log('cdn2', cdn);
    $scope.test = 'hi';
    console.log($scope.test);
  }])

  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
     // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");

  // cdn is available here
  console.log("cdn: ", cdn);

  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: cdn + "views/state1.html",
      controller: 'State1Ctrl'
    })
    .state('state1.list', {
      url: "/list",
      templateUrl: "views/state1.list.html",
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
      }
    })
    .state('state2', {
      url: "/state2",
      templateUrl: "views/state2.html"
    })
    .state('state2.list', {
      url: "/list",
      templateUrl: "views/state2.list.html",
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.things = ["A", "Set", "Of", "Things"];
      }
    });

  }]);

})();
```

Repo here demonstrating problem: `https://github.com/superveetz/Loopback-Tests.git`

1. `npm install` from base.
2. `bower install` from `/client/src`
3. `karma start karma.conf.js` from base.
4. `node .` from base to see `cdn` is avail normally.

Comment: Please list the JS file in your src directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your plugin part in karma.config.

```
plugins: [
  'karma-qunit',
  'karma-ejs-preprocessor',
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-chrome-launcher'
],
```

and run these command.

```
npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev

npm install karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev
```

for further details please check [here](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/plugins.html)

EDIT 1:

Please do thihs changes.

```
inject(function ($injector) {
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      controller = $injector.get('$controller')('State1Ctrl', { $scope: $scope } );
    });
```

Instead of `$rootScope.new()` use `$rootScope.$new()`

Define  `cdn` `console.log('cdn2', cdn)` your cdn so it will not stop your test script

Comment: hey my original problem is happening where `cdn` is still not defined in my tests even though the `index.ejs` file is being preprocessed successfully now :\. I've updated repo and post to reflect file changes.

Comment: Please check EDIT1

Comment: I updated my repo to use the above changes. However the `cdn not defined` error occurs because of this line `templateUrl: cdn + "views/state1.html"` in my `state` declaration. In our actual project, the `cdn` var is generated based on our `NODE_ENV` variable so we can have multiple environments for development and production. I would like my tests to run in a similar fashion where the assets being tested will be based on which `NODE_ENV` the server is running on.

Comment: I'm brand new to unit testing and for some reason I was worried about this `cdn` var having to be pre-processed as it is declared by the server, however this is not required at all. I can simply just declare the variable in a seperate js file as it will always be `"./"` since I probably wouldn't be able to write unit tests for minified code anyways... heh. Thanks.